# Three.js create sphere centered on a cube vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I have a cube and I need to create a small sphere  for each cube vertice, how can I do?I tried to writework something but nothing seems work. Below there is my cube:

```
var geometry0 = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry0.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new     
THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5,   
0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), new    
THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, -0.5)]; 
geometry0.faces = [new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0), new THREE.Face3(4, 5, 6),   
new THREE.Face3(4, 6, 7), new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 5), new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4), new THREE.Face3(1,   
2, 6), new THREE.Face3(1, 6, 5), new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 7), new THREE.Face3(2, 7, 6), new  
THREE.Face3(3, 0, 4), new THREE.Face3(3, 4, 7)]; 

geometry0.computeFaceNormals();
 geometry0.computeVertexNormals();
var material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x39d2dbe7fff39d2, transparent: true, opacity: 0 });
mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry0, material0);
egh0 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh0, 0x000 );
egh0.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate the vertices of the cube, and for each vertice, create a sphere centered in that point.

An example of code could be as follows (drawing red spheres with a radius of 0.2):

```
var spheres = [];
for (var i=0 ; i<geometry0.vertices.length ; i++){
  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2,10,10);
  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000,opacity:1});
  var spheres[i] = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry,sphereMaterial);
  spheres[i].position.set(geometry0.vertices[i].x,
                      geometry0.vertices[i].y,
                      geometry0.vertices[i].z);
  scene.add(spheres[i]);
}
```